# How can I write a vue code demo with it's preview in VuePress?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuepress

For example, I write a vue code in markdown file and it wil be translated to HTML in my website.

Or It will be shown as source code if I use markdown fenced code(` or ```)

I wanna:

- Both HTML and source code
- maybe just write once
- an `expand` and `hide` button

Like `ElementUI` code demo - [a button demo](http://element-cn.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/button).

There is an `expand` button show me the source code and `hide`.

Comment: Maybe you can use the v-html on an element with an js string? Just an suggestion. If you need more info about what I mean, I will try to make an example for you.

Comment: @NielsLucas Yes, I think I need your help.